# R assessing numbers from a sequence to get specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns

if I have a sequence, say:

```
a <- (seq(from=10, to=ncol(x), by=2))
b <- (seq(from=16, to=ncol(x), by=2))
```

and I want to access specific columns in a `data.frame` depending on the sequence, how would I do that in R?

Manually I want to have this:

```
y <- df[, c(10:16, 12:18, 14:20 )]
```

automatically i want something like this:

```
y<-df[, c(a[1]:b[1], a[2]:b[2])]
```

but this does not work.

Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks so much! I tried to find solutions myself but failed.

Comment: `a` and `b` don't have the same length, this will be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same vectors `a` and `b` as @CathG, you can also use `mapply`:

```
y <- x[, mapply(seq, a, b)]
```

Or the faster version

```
y <- x[, mapply(`:`, a, b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing there is no length problem (`a` and `b` have the same length), for example with

```
a<-seq(from=10, to=ncol(x)-6, by=2)
b<-seq(from=16, to=ncol(x), by=2)
```

you can do :

```
y<-df[, as.vector(apply(cbind(a,b),1,function(x){x[1]:x[2]}))]
```